# Best way to find all elements in a list that are present more than k times

Tags: java, array-algorithms

I just came across a problem and I was wondering what would be the best way to solve this.

I have a List of Lists

```
L = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12], [3, 6, 9, 12, 15], ....]
```

Assuming the size of **L** is **n**, what would be the best way to find all the elements that are present **k** or more times in **L**?

For example, if `k = 2`, then I should get
`[2, 3, 4, 6, 12]`.

Comment: Do you mean *array of arrays*?

Comment: @Gendarme does that matter in this case? Just some list-like container for ``int``s.

Comment: Flatten the list/array and get the frequency.

Comment: Yes. An array of arrays, an ArrayList of ArrayLists (if you are using Java) or something similar.

Comment: @thisisshantzz where's the code we can help you with?

Comment: The first sub-array has the size of 7, the second has the size of 6, the third has the size of 5. Is this intentional? Do you only have seven sub-arrays?

Comment: The individual arrays/lists can have arbitrary lengths. What you see here is just an example.

Comment: I am on my phone right now. I will add a code snippet once I get home. For now though, I am running a nested loop to get the counts and store them in a HashMap.

Comment: what do you mean with "best way"? the way with the least iterations?

Comment: Best in this case would be fastest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Assuming the size of L is n, what would be the best way to find all the elements that are present k or more times in L?

Traditional way is to iterate through each list one time and collect times values in `HashMap<Integer, Integer>` (where key is a number, value is times). Then you need just to collect all the keys from map which values are `k` or more:

```
 public static List<Integer> getResultListByMap(List<List<Integer>> inputList, int k) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> times = new HashMap<>();
    for (List<Integer> integers : inputList) {
        for (Integer integer : integers) {
            if (times.keySet().contains(integer)) {
                times.put(integer, times.get(integer) + 1);
            } else {
                times.put(integer, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : times.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue() >= k) {
            result.add(entry.getKey());
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

`result` list contains all the numbers which are presented in lists `k` or more times

**UPDATE:** OK, I've got that you use `HashMap` approach already and it is slow for you. I wrote an algorithm with Java 8 Stream API features which uses lists concatenation, sorting and gains bonuses from parallelism:

```
public static List<Integer> getResultListBySort(List<List<Integer>> inputList, int k) {
    List<Integer> newList = inputList.parallelStream()
            .flatMap(l -> l.parallelStream()).sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());

    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();

    Integer prev = null;
    int sum = newList.get(0);
    for (Integer integer : newList) {
        if (integer.equals(prev)) {
            sum++;
        } else {
            if (sum >= k) {
                result.add(integer);
            }
            sum = 1;
        }
        prev = integer;
    }
    return result;
}
```

It is twice as fast for `2000 x 2000` problem size  - 2000 lists with 2000 elements (now it takes only half a second to get the result list on my PC)

```
Benchmark                       Mode  Samples  Score  Score error  Units
c.c.b.MyBenchmark.testMap       avgt       20  0,972        0,030   s/op
c.c.b.MyBenchmark.testSorted    avgt       20  0,534        0,005   s/op
```

Comment: ``times.put(integer, 0);`` is not correct, is it? Wouldn't you put the value ``1`` into the map when you just encountered that number for the first time?

Comment: I'm not talking about autoboxing, I'm talking about the value which should be ``1`` and not ``0``.

Comment: I am doing the exact same thing but I wanted to know if there was a way to do this without having to run that nested loop. In my specific case, n = 3 and the individual lists themselves can have around 2000 elements. So it is a little slow.

Comment: If not a list of lists, then is there a better way to do this? What I have are n conditions and a list of values that satisfy each condition. What I want to find is how many values satisfy k or more conditions.

Answer (score 0):

It completely depends upon the frequency of operations performed on L. Consider you are doing this operation once in a while then it's fine to find the result with O(n_1+n_2+n_3+...+n_n) time complexity. i.e., Finding out every time by iterating through array of arrays and counting. If it's a frequent operation why not sort the array of arrays or why not use caching. I believe that the best way completely depends on your usage.

Answer (score 0):

Maintain an extra count array that stores the count of elements traversed completely. Then, traverse the list while updating the count of elements, and while updating if an element's count equals k, add it to final answer list, which is initially empty. But for this to work you should the know the maximum element that is in the given array.

```
final_answer = []
count = [0 for i in range(max_el)] # put very large number here e.g. 1000
for sublist in L:
    for element in sublist:
        count[element] += 1
        if count[element] == k:
            final_list.append(element)
```

print(final_answer)